# Spring REST Json: save field as JSON String

Tags: spring, jackson, spring-restcontroller, spring-rest

I have a Spring REST controller that serializes an entity (default behaviour). For one of the fields of this entity I would like to save the actual Json (and not deserialize it).

For example:

Entity:

```
class Person:
  String name
  String data
```

Post to `/person/1`

```
{
  'name': 'John', 
  'data': {'age': 35, 'job': 'engineer'}
}
```

The default deserialization won't handle `{'age': 35, 'job': 'engineer'}` as a String value. It throws an exception (com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException).

Is there a way to accomplish this easily? 
I prefer to not write my own serializer/deserializer.

Comment: isn't as easy as adding some quotes around the string ?  `"{'age': 35, 'job': 'engineer'}"` ? ... i didn't try it though

Comment: What about `Map<String, Object> data`? A specific bean holding the `age` and `job` properties could be better.

Comment: @Pras: yes, that is easy, but not what we want. We would like to make it pure JSON outside of our application.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8137060/jackson-deserialize-variable-as-json-string, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4783421/how-can-i-include-raw-json-in-an-object-using-jackson