# Keeping some JSON field as String when deserializing using Jackson

Tags: android, json, jackson, retrofit2, fasterxml

I'm using `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind` with **Retrofit** to handle the response from the server in my Android app.

Since the `JSONObject` response is too complicated and contains lots of `JSONArray`, I want to be able to parse some of those array fields into String instead of creating POJO for each sub-object that those Array could contains.

Is there a way I could just tell **Jackson** to keep those field as String and not parse them into Entities?

Comment: check link http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-deserialization

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jackson Deserialize Variable as Json String](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8137060/jackson-deserialize-variable-as-json-string)

Comment: You can use annotation [`@JsonRawValue`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.0.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonRawValue.html).