# How can Spring restful API return JSON format string in real JSON format instead of a string

Tags: json, spring, rest

I'm writing restful API with Spring. The API looks like below which lists all objects of its type.

http://192.168.1.100:8021/some/api/v3/someobjs

The DTO looks like below

```java
public class SomeDTO {

  @NotBlank
  @Size(min = 1, max = 32, message = "Name size must be between 1 and 32.")
  private String name;

  @NotBlank
  @Size(min = 1, max = 4000, message = "Info size must be between 1 and 4000.")
  private String info;

  // Setter & Getter
}
```

The "info" value could be a JSON format string. So, what I got could be like this:

```java
{
  "name": "wpdfw",
  "info": "{\n    \"indexName\": \"wpdfw\", \n    \"urls\": [\n        \"https://www.example.com/l2/api/v1\", \n        \"https://www.example.com/l3/api/v1\"\n    ], \n    \"regions\": [\n        \"wp.*.*\", \n        \"wf.*.*\"\n    ], \n    \"policy\": \"equal\"\n}"
}
```

However, I want the "info" to be in real JSON format instead of a string:

```
{
  "name": "wpdfw",
  "info": {
    "indexName": "wpdfw",
    "urls": ["https://www.example.com/l2/api/v1", "https://www.example.com/l3/api/v2"],
    "regions": ["wp.*.*", "wf.*.*"],
    "policy": "equal"
  }
}
```

Please note that the JSON format "info" value could be of any JSON hierarchical structure which is unknown.
How can I do it?

Comment: supoose this [post](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/) may help you get started with Spring Data Rest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4783421/how-can-i-include-raw-json-in-an-object-using-jackson).

Check the `@JsonRawValue` which has 
`@Target(value={ANNOTATION_TYPE,METHOD,FIELD})`.

`@JsonRawValue
public String getInfo() { return info; }`

Spring Rest uses Jackson library for serializing to JSON.

Depending on the library you have on your classpath you can have Jackson v1 or v2.

Also check [this link](http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-annotations) that can help you with additional examples of using Jackson annotations.