# How to parse a Java List of already parsed JSON into a Big JSON?

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson, json-serialization

I use `Jackson` to `serialize/deserialize` `JSON`.

I have a `List<String>` in which all elements inside are already `serialized` in `JSON` format. I would like to generate a big `JSON` from that `List`.

In other word, I have:

```
List<String> a = new ArrayList<>();
a[0] = JSON_0
a[1] = JSON_1
...
a[N] = JSON_N
```

And I would like to render:

```
[
   {JSON_0},
   {JSON_1},
   ...
   {JSON_N}
]
```

What is the best way to do so using `Jackson`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the simpler solution would be to create `ArrayNode` and use [addRawValue](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/node/ArrayNode.html#addRawValue-com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.util.RawValue-) method:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ArrayNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.util.RawValue;

public class JsonApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        ArrayNode nodes = mapper.getNodeFactory().arrayNode();
        nodes.addRawValue(new RawValue("{}"));
        nodes.addRawValue(new RawValue("true"));
        nodes.addRawValue(new RawValue("{\"id\":1}"));

        System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(nodes));
    }
}
```

Above code prints:

```
[{},true,{"id":1}]
```

You can also, create a `POJO` with list and use `@JsonRawValue` annotation. But if you can not have extra root object you need to implement custom serialiser for it. Example with `POJO` and custom serialiser:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonSerializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonSerialize;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class JsonApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        List<String> jsons = new ArrayList<>();
        jsons.add("{}");
        jsons.add("true");
        jsons.add("{\"id\":1}");

        RawJsons root = new RawJsons();
        root.setJsons(jsons);
        System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(root));
    }
}

@JsonSerialize(using = RawJsonSerializer.class)
class RawJsons {

    private List<String> jsons;

    public List<String> getJsons() {
        return jsons;
    }

    public void setJsons(List<String> jsons) {
        this.jsons = jsons;
    }
}

class RawJsonSerializer extends JsonSerializer<RawJsons> {

    @Override
    public void serialize(RawJsons value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException {
        gen.writeStartArray();
        if (value != null && value.getJsons() != null) {
            for (String json : value.getJsons()) {
                gen.writeRawValue(json);
            }
        }
        gen.writeEndArray();
    }
}
```

If you need to have `SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT` feature enabled for all items in array, you need to deserialise all inner objects and serialise them again.

See also:

- [How can I include raw JSON in an object using Jackson?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4783421/how-can-i-include-raw-json-in-an-object-using-jackson)
- [Handling raw JSON values using Jackson](https://dolzhenko.me/blog/2017-08-13-raw-jackson)

Comment: That's it ! Thank you for your time. It was very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

the simple fact of having the character '[' we are marking that it is an array so what I recommend to put the list into a JSON array.

I would need a little more information to help you, since it doesn't make much sense to use a JSON String, since a JSON is composed of Key / Value, it is best to make a bean / object with the attribute.
Example:

```
class Object {
    private String attribute = value;
}

{attribute: value}
```