# Change one field from string to json object in jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a class where `employeeDetails` is being read from a data store as json string.

```
public class Employee {
  private String name;

  @JsonProperty("employeeDetails")
  @JsonSerialize(???)
  private String employeeDetailsBlob;

  // getters and setters
}
```

Now I want to return employeeDetails(dynamic type) as an object in my response. I have changed the name using `@JsonProperty` and all the examples I have is for using `@JsonSerialize(using = Employee.class)`.

So my response should look like this

```
{name: "foo", employeeDetails: { age: 21 }}
```

What I am getting is

```
{name: "foo", employeeDetails: "{ age: 21 }"}
```

I can add `@JsonSerialize` to my class but then I have to handle all the fields myself and do something like this in the overridden method.

```
jgen.writeFieldName("employeeDetails");
SerializedString serializedString = new SerializedString(empl.getEmployeeDetailsBlob());
jgen.writeRawValue(serializedString);
```

Is there a way I can do it using annotations and that too only on the field I want to change from json string to json object.

Comment: If employeeDetailsBlob is a POJO then that will happen automatically. No need to specify anything

Comment: Remove the JsonSerialize annotation

Comment: Yes, it's a POJO. But I am getting a string, and I want a json object.

Comment: By default you should be getting a JSON object, not a string

Comment: I have added @JsonSerializer just for reference, in the actual code, it's not there and I am getting a string.

Comment: Can you specify what framework you're using?

Comment: springboot, lombok, jackson

Comment: Try to use [JsonRawValue](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.10/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonRawValue.html), and take a look at: [How to parse a Java List of already parsed JSON into a Big JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57731892/how-to-parse-a-java-list-of-already-parsed-json-into-a-big-json/57762896#57762896)

Comment: Yes sir, adding `@JsonRawValue` did the trick. Thanks heaps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `@JsonRawValue` did the trick.

```
public class Employee {
   private String name;

   @JsonProperty("employeeDetails")
   @JsonRawValue
   private String employeeDetailsBlob;

   // getters and setters
}
```

Comment: Why are you keeping your field as a string? You said it was a POJO

Comment: I am reading it from a datastore and it comes out as a string and when I had to send the response, I need to send an object.

Comment: Ah, so you should have built a POJO from that string... But maybe that's Overkill

Comment: Yes, moreover I don't know the type of the employeeDetailsBlob

Comment: Thanks again @DavidBrossard