# How to map various possible types of a JSON field to a POJO attribute?

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson, rabbitmq

I have a POJO which is used for mapping the values received from rabbitmq. The messages are sent from other third-party services which I don't have control over. The problem is that these services don't send the certain fields in a consistent manner.

For example, in the case of an `error` field, this field will only have information when the third-party service wants to send a message to inform that there is an error. Some services may send in their JSON message to the queue this way:

```
{
   id: 123,
   name: "PersonA",
   error: null
}
```

And then there are also services that may send their JSON message this way:

```
{
   id: 123,
   name: "PersonA",
   error: []
}
```

And there are also services that may just omit the field entirely:

```
{
   id: 123,
   name: "PersonA"
}
```

Of course, if there is an error, that error field will contain fields within it:

```
{
   id: 123,
   name: "PersonA",
   error: {
      message: "Cannot find PersonA"
   }
}
```

So, there is a chance that the error field can be `null`, `undefined`, `array` or an `object`.
The problem is, I can only define a single type in my POJO for the `error` field.

```
public class MyMessage {
    private int id;
    private MessageError error;
    private String name;

    @JsonCreator
    public MyMessage(
        @JsonProperty("id") int id,
        @JsonProperty("error") MessageError error,     // error is a MessageError object already but what is sent in could be null, undefined, an array or an object
        @JsonProperty("name") String name
    ) {
        this.id = id;
        this.error = error;
        this.name = name;
    }
}

public class MessageError {
    private String message;

    @JsonCreator
    public MessageError(
        @JsonProperty("message") String message
    ) {
        this.message = message;
    }
}
```

I'm using Spring with Jackson.
In this case, how can I handle and map all the possible values that maybe assigned to the `error` field in the message to the POJO when it gets deserialised?

Comment: I think the best way is using `JsonNode` as `error`

Comment: Agreed with @Deadpool 's comment. BTW, all of your JSON strings are not legal, the key name of each field should be wrapped in double-quote.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have any markers in the json data to identify its source and thus its shape, I would try to set error field type to object, and if it doesn't work or fit, to "json raw" as explained in answers of [How can I include raw JSON in an object using Jackson?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4783421/114139)
So you can proceed the error field in the appropriate way according to the content you would discover at runtime, peeking from expected ones you detailed above.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to resolve this problem is to define `error` field as a common `Object` type

```java
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({
"id",
"name",
"error"
})
public class MyMessage {

@JsonProperty("id")
private int id;
@JsonProperty("name")
private String name;
@JsonProperty("error")
private Object error;

@JsonProperty("id")
public int getId() {
return id;
}

@JsonProperty("id")
public void setId(int id) {
this.id = id;
}

@JsonProperty("name")
public String getName() {
return name;
}

@JsonProperty("name")
public void setName(String name) {
this.name = name;
}

@JsonProperty("error")
public Object getError() {
return error;
}

@JsonProperty("error")
public void setError(Object error) {
this.error = error;
}

}
```

And then you have to map it to another DTO:

```java
// someplace where you will map it

MyMessage message = source.getMessageFromQueue();

if(message.getError() == null) {
  // do something
} else {
   Object error = message.getError();
   handleError(error);
}

private void handleError(Object error) {
   if(error instanceOf MessageError) {
       handleMessageError((MessageError) error) // handle as known MessageError object 
   } else if(error instanceOf String) {
       handleStringError((String) error) // handle as String, write in logs maybe
   } else if(error instanceOf List) {
       handleErrors((String) error) // handle as List errors
   } else {
       handleUndefinedError()
   }
}
```