# No serializer found for class org.jooq.JSON and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer

Tags: java, rest, serialization, jooq

By implementing a method as a service for API, I faced this problem

> No serializer found for class org.jooq.JSON and no properties
> discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable
> SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through reference chain:
> java.util.ArrayList[0]-> db.jooq.tables.pojos.Query["queryJson"])

The Jooq POJO of my Query (TABLE) is :

```
 private Integer id; 
 private JSON    queryJson;
```

and the method which give a list of query as a respond is

```
 @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)   public Response
 getQueries(@PathParam("ownerId") String ownerId,
       @PathParam("roomId") String hotelroom) throws JsonProcessingException {
     List<Query> queries = DatabaseUtil.getQueries(dsl, UUID.fromString(hotelroom));
     return Response.ok(queries).build();}
```

But there is no serialize and if I change the jooq POJO to this :

```
private Integer id; 
private String queryJson;
```

Then the output of my response will have no error by serializing.
Does any one have an idea, how to solve this problem in jooq?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using Jackson, you can annotate your `JSON` property with [`JsonRawValue`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4783421/521799):

```java
private Integer id; 
@JsonRawValue
private JSON    queryJson;
```

If you need to also read the value from JSON, you can do this:

```java
private Integer id; 
@JsonRawValue
@JsonDeserialize(using = JSONDeserializer.class)
private JSON    queryJson;
```

... with:

```java
class JSONDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<JSON> {

    @Override
    public JSON deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt)
    throws IOException {
        Object t = p.readValueAsTree();
        return t == null ? null : JSON.json("" + t);
    }
}
```

A future jOOQ version (not yet 3.16), might offer native support in the code generator for such annotations: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/13333

Answer (score 0):

You cannot annotate fields in the generated JOOQ sources because the custom annotation will be overriden during the next code generation.

While looking for the answer, I found [this blog post](https://medium.com/@sahilseth/custom-serialisers-with-jackson-jooq-and-spring-boot-da8fb9494813).

To sum up, you need to create a custom serializer that will allow Jackson to understand how to serialize the `org.jooq.JSON` objects.

```java
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.StdSerializer;
import org.jooq.JSON;

import java.io.IOException;

public class JooqJsonSerializer extends StdSerializer<JSON> {
    public JooqJsonSerializer() {
        super(JSON.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void serialize(JSON value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException {
        gen.writeRawValue(value.data());
    }
}
```

Then configure the Jackson to use it by adding the configuration method in any of the Spring `@Configuration` classes you should already have.

```java
@Bean
public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer jsonCustomizer() {
    return builder ->
            builder.serializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.USE_DEFAULTS)
                    .serializers(new JooqJsonSerializer());
}
```